# how to schedule .sh script on linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file, sh

I'm new to linux, and I have linux server with script `ftp.sh` which transfers files to windows server.

I have tried to schedule it at 06:15 every day via crontab command in PUTTY/winSCP

```
 15 06 * * * sh ftp.sh
```

and get this error message:

```
command not found
```

I have also tried to schedule it from a Windows batch file with

```
start folderName\putty.exe -ssh root@10.*.*.* 22 -pw "password"
```

It succeeds with the login, but can't execute navigation to `/opt/dan/scripts` or execute the `sh ftp.sh` command in it.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way I havn't thought about?

Comment: Put the full path of the script ftp.sh on the cron entry.

Comment: This question may be more suitable for serverfault.

Comment: @AlbertoRe 
what do you mean on the cron entry?

Answer (score 1):

sh cannot execute ftp.sh since ftp.sh is propably not in the PATH environment variable. If you write the full path to ftp.sh you may succeed.

15 06 * * * sh /the/path/to/ftp.sh

Or depending on your setup

15 06 * * * /path/to/sh /the/path/to/ftp.sh

Or

15 06 * * * /the/path/to/ftp.sh

Answer (score 1):

Your OS doesn't seem to recognise 'sh' as a command, as stated here:

```
command not found
```

This usually means it's not installed on the particular flavour of Linux you're using. You should use a different file interpreter, or if you're sure that 'sh' is installed then you should use the absolute path to that program in the cron command.

If you type the following in to a terminal session, it should bring up the full path:

```
whereis sh
```

Or alternatively:

```
which sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more about the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). It is not the same in interactive shells (they usually set it in your `~/.bashrc`) and in cron jobs.

So specify an absolute path for your `ftp.sh` shell script in your `crontab` and start that script with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) like `#!/bin/sh`

BTW, consider switching to Linux entirely (e.g. by installing some Linux distribution on your laptop)